# Android search (EditText) function inside fragment expandablelistview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, search, expandablelistview

Need some help for implement search function in my android app that displays `expandablelistview` in a fragment. I've found many examples on the web but none of them has the same approach (Fragment + Expandablelistview).

### Expandable_adapter Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.genesysci.leo.R;
import com.genesysci.leo.others.Child;

public class Expandable_adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{


    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private Context _context;
    private ArrayList<String>_listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Child>> _listDataChild;
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Child>> _listDataChildTemp;
    //= new HashMap <String, ArrayList<Child>>();

    public Expandable_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Child>> listDataChild) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listDataChild;
        this._listDataChildTemp = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Child>>();
        _listDataChildTemp.putAll(_listDataChild);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child, null);

        }
        TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_listchild);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        image.setImageBitmap(child.getImage());
        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img2);
        image2.setImageBitmap(child.getImage());


        String toto = " ";
        String toto1 = " ";
        if (child.getName() != null) {
            toto = child.getName();
        }
        else {
            toto = "";
        }

        if (child.getSubject() != null) {
            toto1 = child.getSubject();
        }
        else {
            toto1 = "";
        }
        expandedListTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(toto + " " + toto1));

        //expandedListTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(childText));
        expandedListTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }
        TextView listTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_listtitle);
        listTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listTitle.setText(headerTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public void filter (String text) {
        _listDataChild.clear();

        //HashSet<String> headerData = new HashSet<String>();
        //Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        //HashMap<String, ArrayList<Child>> _listDataChildTemp = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Child>>();

        ArrayList<Child> testData = null;
        //Child testData = null;

        if(text.isEmpty()){
            _listDataChildTemp.putAll(_listDataChild);
        }

        else {
            for (Map.Entry <String, ArrayList<Child>> entry : _listDataChildTemp.entrySet()) {

                String key = entry.getKey();

                testData = new ArrayList<Child>();

                if(testData.getClass().getName().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())){
                    _listDataChild.put(key,testData);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

### Child Class

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Child {

    private String Name;
    private String Subject;
    private Bitmap Image;
    private Bitmap Image2;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return Subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String Subject) {
        this.Subject = Subject;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap Image) {
        this.Image = Image;
    }
}
```

### Fragment Class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.genesysci.leo.R;
import com.genesysci.leo.activity.MainActivity;
import com.genesysci.leo.models.Expandable_adapter;
import com.genesysci.leo.others.Child;
import com.genesysci.leo.others.HttpHandler;


public class UrielFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    String url = "http://192.168.8.100/Android/jsonData.php";
    private ProgressDialog mprocessingdialog;
    private TextView tv_welcomeuser, tv_recentupdate;
    ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
    private ExpandableListView exp_leaseoffer;
    private ArrayList<String> listDataHeader;
    View rootView;
    ImageView image;


    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Child>> listDataChild;
    Dialog dialog;
    String flash = "";
    private void save() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ".............", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public class Wrapper {
        Void result;
        Bitmap decodedByte;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wellcome_page, container, false);
        //tv_welcomeuser = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_welcomeuser);
        //tv_recentupdate = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_recentupdate);
        //FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        //fab.setTitle("Familie");
        //fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.allan1));
        //fab.setIcon(R.drawable.world_map);
        //fab.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI);
        //fab.setColorNormalResId(R.color.red);
        //fab.setColorPressedResId(R.color.black_semi_transparent);

        image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        exp_leaseoffer = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        exp_leaseoffer.setGroupIndicator(null);
        exp_leaseoffer.setChildIndicator(null);
        exp_leaseoffer.setChildDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.white));
        exp_leaseoffer.setDividerHeight(0);
        exp_leaseoffer.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        SearchView  searchview = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search);
        searchview.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchview.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchview.setQueryRefinementEnabled(false);
        searchview.setQueryHint("Search");

        searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {

                //can't resolve method filter
                    expandableListAdapter.filter(text);
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {

                //can't resolve method filter
                expandableListAdapter.filter(text);
                return false;
            }
        });

        /*fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new DownloadJason().execute();
            }
        });*/

        new DownloadJason().execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    private class DownloadJason extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Wrapper> {
        String jsonstr = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
            mprocessingdialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            //mprocessingdialog.setTitle(" Veuillez patienter...");
            mprocessingdialog.setMessage("chargement...");
            mprocessingdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mprocessingdialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Wrapper doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            Wrapper w = new Wrapper();

            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            HttpHandler jp = new HttpHandler();
                try {
                    // test si serveur joignable
                    URL urlServer = new URL("http://192.168.8.100");
                    HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlServer.openConnection();
                    urlConn.setConnectTimeout(3000); //<- 3Seconds Timeout
                    urlConn.connect();
                    // si bon code recu
                    if (urlConn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        try {
                            jsonstr = jp.makeServiceCall(url);
                            writeToFile(jsonstr);
                        } catch ( NullPointerException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e1.getMessage());
                }
                try {
                    // essai lecture locale
                    jsonstr = readFromFile();
                }
                catch ( NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                listDataChild = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Child>>();

            if (jsonstr != null) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
                    JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int hk = 0; hk < jarray.length(); hk++) {
                        JSONObject d = jarray.getJSONObject(hk);
                        String mimi = d.getString("phone_number");

                        if (mimi.equalsIgnoreCase("600")) {
                            flash = "FoudreNoire";
                        }
                        else {
                            flash = "Maracaibo";
                        }


                        // Adding Header data

                        listDataHeader.add(d.getString("name"));

                        // Adding child data for lease offer
                        ArrayList<Child> lease_offer = new ArrayList<Child>();

                        Child ch = new Child();
                        Child ch2 = new Child();
                        Child ch3 = new Child();
                        ch.setName(d.getString("name"));
                        ch3.setSubject(d.getString("subject"));

                        String image = d.getString("phone_number");

                        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,decodedString.length);
                        ch2.setImage(decodedByte);

                        //lease_offer.add(d.getString("name") + " " + flash + " " + d.getString("id"));
                        //lease_offer.add(d.getString("subject"));
                        //lease_offer.add("Contacts : "+d.getString("phone_number"));
                        lease_offer.add(ch);
                        lease_offer.add(ch2);
                        lease_offer.add(ch3);
                        // Header into Child data
                        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(hk), lease_offer);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    //afficher notification acces internet requis
                    notifyNoConnection();
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.d("Json url view", "Empty");
                // Server call failed
            }

            return w;
        }

        private void writeToFile(String data) {
            try {
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(getActivity().openFileOutput("18621", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
                osw.write(data);
                osw.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        private String readFromFile() {

            String ret = "";

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getActivity().openFileInput("18621");

                if ( inputStream != null ) {
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                    String receiveString = "";
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                        stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                    }
                    inputStream.close();
                    ret = stringBuilder.toString();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
            }

            return ret;
        }

        private void notifyNoConnection() {
            Handler handler =  new Handler(getActivity().getMainLooper());
            handler.post( new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    noConnection();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Wrapper w) {
            super.onPostExecute(w);
            mprocessingdialog.dismiss();

            expandableListAdapter = new Expandable_adapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);


            Log.i("groups", listDataHeader.toString());

            exp_leaseoffer.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

            exp_leaseoffer.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            // Listview Group expanded listener
            exp_leaseoffer.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
                int previousItem = -1;

                @Override
                        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                            if(groupPosition != previousItem )
                                exp_leaseoffer.collapseGroup(previousItem );
                            previousItem = groupPosition;
                        }
                    });
            exp_leaseoffer.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                        // Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            exp_leaseoffer.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
        }
    }

    public void openDialog() {

        dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        TextView m = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_info);
        m.setText(R.string.dialog_text);
        final Button n = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel);
        final Button p = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok);
        dialog.show();
        n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        p.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void noConnection() {

        dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_retry);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        TextView m = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.retry_dialog);
        m.setText(R.string.dialog_text_no_connection);
        final Button n = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.retry_retry);
        final Button p = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.retry_close);
        dialog.show();
        n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                new DownloadJason().execute();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        p.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: add SearchView and  add textchange listener and filter your list

Comment: @Ganesh ,can you provide an example according to my code approach pls?

Comment: Please try this http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-expandablelistview-search.html

Comment: @Ganesh, thanks i tried this but can't get the filter (onTextChanged)  work (adapter is based on base_expandable adapter). Can't type in searchview. and many over "incompatibles" approaches. So i hope to try something closiest to my initial code.

Comment: Please check my edited answer i have edited your adapter code

Comment: @Ganesh any help ??? :)

Comment: what is the issue that u r facing now

Comment: can't call filter method from adapter (is filter right??), please see the edited fragment class and adapter @Ganesh

Comment: where is your ExpandableListAdapter.class ? it looks like Expandable_adapter.class right

Answer (score 1):

Please try this i think it will solve your problem

```
        SearchView  searchview=  (SearchView)viewlayout.findViewById(R.id.searchview);
        searchview.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchview.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchview.setQueryRefinementEnabled(false);
        searchview.setQueryHint("Search by name");
        searchview.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);

        searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        if(unCapAdapter!=null){
        adapter.filter(query);// add filter method in your adapter

        }
        return false;
        }
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        adapter.filter(query);

        return false;
        }
        });
```

//Your adapter code

```
     import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.List;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.graphics.Typeface;
        import android.text.Html;
        import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import com.genesysci.leo.R;
        import com.genesysci.leo.others.Child;

public class Expandable_adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{


    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private Context _context;
    private ArrayList<String>_listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String, List<Child>> _listDataChild;

    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Child>> _listDataChildTemp=new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Child>>();


    public Expandable_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<String>      listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<Child>> listDataChild) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listDataChild;

        _listDataChildTemp.putAll(listChildData);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child, null);

        }
        TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_listchild);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        image.setImageBitmap(child.getImage());
        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img2);
        image2.setImageBitmap(child.getImage());


        String toto = " ";
        String toto1 = " ";
        if (child.getName() != null) {
            toto = child.getName();
        }
        else {
            toto = "";
        }

        if (child.getSubject() != null) {
            toto1 = child.getSubject();
        }
        else {
            toto1 = "";
        }
        expandedListTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(toto + " " + toto1));

        //expandedListTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(childText));
        expandedListTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }
        TextView listTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_listtitle);
        listTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listTitle.setText(headerTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public void filter(String text){
        _listDataChild.clear();

        HashSet<String> headerData=new HashSet<String>();
        ArrayList<Child> testData=null;

        if(text.isEmpty()){
            _listDataChild.putAll(_listDataChildTemp);

        }else{
            for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Child>> entry : _listDataChildTemp.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                testData=new ArrayList<Child>();
                    if(testData.getName().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())){
                      _listDataChild.put(key,testData);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me the filter side? how to filter expandablelistview ? (pls take a look to my adapter)

Comment: i think you are getting data from server

Comment: so which filter you want to apply server side or within list ?

Comment: filter within list because the list still accessible if no network access (json datas are stored locally)

Comment: i made minors change to your edited answer, but stuck with "unresolved symbol" here 

'if(testData.getName().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())){
                    _listDataChild.put(key,testData);
                }'

can't resolve getName symbol

Comment: getName() is your Child bean method

Comment: please take a look to edited adapter code.
of course getName is a method from Child class, but it is one of the problems i encounter when i tried to implement something like this sample example [http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-expandablelistview-search.html](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-expandablelistview-search.html)

Answer (score 0):

My fragment

```
Loader lm;

lm = new loader(ctx, feeList);
```

This is my Adapter class

```
public class loader extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{

    private Context slcntx;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private String url;
    private Bitmap bmp;

    public loader() {
        this.data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    }


    public loader(Context ctx, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        slcntx = ctx;
        data=d;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)slcntx.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Create ImageLoader object to download and show image in list
        // Call ImageLoader constructor to initialize FileCache

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(slcntx);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void clearData() { data.clear(); }

    /********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
    public static class ViewHolder{

        public TextView tv1;
        public TextView tv2;
        public TextView tv3;
        public TextView tv4;
        ImageView image;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        HashMap<String, String> pers = new HashMap<String, String>();

        pers = data.get(position);

        if(convertView==null) {

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.allfees, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.tv2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.month);
            holder.tv3 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.amount);
            holder.tv4 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.date);

            holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.profileimage);


            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        // holder.teacherTV.setText(""+position);

        /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
//            vi.setTag( holder );
        holder.tv1.setText(pers.get("studentname"));   

        holder.tv2.setText(pers.get("month"));

        holder.tv3.setText("₹");
        holder.tv3.append(pers.get("amount"));



        holder.tv4.setText(getDate(Long.parseLong(pers.get("paiddate")), "dd-MM-yyyy"));


        ImageView image = holder.image;

        url = pers.get("urls");
        System.out.println(url);

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, image);

           /* try {

                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url).getContent());
                holder.image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
*/



        /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row ***********/
        //vi.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(position));
        return vi;
    }

    public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
    {
        // Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

        // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Image Loader Class

```
public class ImageLoader {

    // Initialize MemoryCache
    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();

    FileCache fileCache;

    //Create Map (collection) to store image and image url in key value pair
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;

    //handler to display images in UI thread
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public ImageLoader(Context context){

        fileCache = new FileCache(context);

        // Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of
        // threads operating off a shared unbounded queue.
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    }

    // default image show in list (Before online image download)
    final int stub_id=R.drawable.location;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //Store image and url in Map
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);

        //Check image is stored in MemoryCache Map or not (see MemoryCache.java)
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);

        if(bitmap!=null){
            // if image is stored in MemoryCache Map then
            // Show image in listview row
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else
        {
            //queue Photo to download from url
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);

            //Before downloading image show default image
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        // Store image and url in PhotoToLoad object
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);

        // pass PhotoToLoad object to PhotosLoader runnable class
        // and submit PhotosLoader runnable to executers to run runnable
        // Submits a PhotosLoader runnable task for execution

        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                //Check if image already downloaded
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                // download image from web url
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);

                // set image data in Memory Cache
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);

                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;

                // Get bitmap to display
                BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);

                // Causes the Runnable bd (BitmapDisplayer) to be added to the message queue.
                // The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.
                // BitmapDisplayer run method will call
                handler.post(bd);

            }catch(Throwable th){
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        //CHECK : if trying to decode file which not exist in cache return null
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        // Download image file from web
        try {

            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();

            // Constructs a new FileOutputStream that writes to file
            // if file not exist then it will create file
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);

            // See Utils class CopyStream method
            // It will each pixel from input stream and
            // write pixels to output stream (file)
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);

            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();

            //Now file created and going to resize file with defined height
            // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);

            return bitmap;

        } catch (Throwable ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    //Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){

        try {

            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
            stream1.close();

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.

            // Set width/height of recreated image
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=85;

            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
              if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with current scale values
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){

        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        //Check url is already exist in imageViews MAP
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;

            // Show bitmap on UI
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        //Clear cache directory downloaded images and stored data in maps
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

File Cache class

```
public class FileCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context){

        //Find the dir at SDCARD to save cached images

        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        {
            //if SDCARD is mounted (SDCARD is present on device and mounted)
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"");
        }

        else
        {
            // if checking on simulator the create cache dir in your application context
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
            //cacheDir = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "LazyList");
        }

        if(!cacheDir.exists()){
            // create cache dir in your application context
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    public File getFile(String url){
        //Identify images by hashcode or encode by URLEncoder.encode.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());

        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear(){
        // list all files inside cache directory
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return;
        //delete all cache directory files
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

Memory Cache class

```
public class MemoryCache {

    private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";

    //Last argument true for LRU ordering
    private Map<String, Bitmap> cache = Collections.synchronizedMap(
            new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f,true));

   //current allocated size
    private long size=0; 

    //max memory cache folder used to download images in bytes
    private long limit=1000000; 

    public MemoryCache(){

        //use 25% of available heap size
        setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/4);
    }

    public void setLimit(long new_limit){

        limit=new_limit;
        Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to "+limit/1024./1024.+"MB");
    }

    public Bitmap get(String id){
        try{
            if(!cache.containsKey(id))
                return null;
            //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78 
            return cache.get(id);
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
        try{
            if(cache.containsKey(id))
                size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
            cache.put(id, bitmap);
            size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
            checkSize();
        }catch(Throwable th){
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        Log.i(TAG, "cache size="+size+" length="+cache.size());
        if(size>limit){
            Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();//least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated  
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
                size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                iter.remove();
                if(size<=limit)
                    break;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size "+cache.size());
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        try{
            //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78 
            cache.clear();
            size=0;
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(bitmap==null)
            return 0;
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}
```

Utlis class

```
public class Utils
{
    public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
    {
        {
            final int buffer_size=1024;
            try
            {

                byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
                for(;;)
                {
                    //Read byte from input stream

                    int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
                    if(count==-1)
                        break;

                    //Write byte from output stream
                    os.write(bytes, 0, count);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    }
}
```

Search code:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    TextInputEditText te1;
    Button b1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Returning the layout file after inflating
        //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_get_user_by_id, container, false);

        //getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

        te1 = (TextInputEditText) view.findViewById(R.id.userid);
        b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.getuser);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //Call the API and retriev the results
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: I got the similar kind of issue and got this as my resolution.

Comment: why are you adding to much of code just add the solution

Comment: Sorry, @Ganesh I thought it would be self-explanatory

Comment: @SumitShetty , i don't really understand your answer. i don't see any 'search" anywhere in your code.

Comment: Search is quite easy, just create an edittext and a button and an onclick listener for the button after the button click you can write the above code to get it done.

Comment: If you have any doubt in search please ask!

Comment: @SumitShetty no need to add edittext and button simply add a Serachview

Comment: @SumitShetty,  search is really easy, i've implemented successfully with simple listview in activity, expandablelistview in activity, but in my case i have to implement it in fragment with GroupView and ChildView. Since 2 weeks i tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: @Ganesh I did not ever try Searchview seems its correct time to try it out. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @Origin I just used listview in a fragment and above code is of that module itself

Comment: @SumitShetty, can you post your search sample part? it may really help me :)

Comment: I edited my answer @Origin please have a look at it.

Comment: @SumitShetty, thx for your efforts but it seems you only show the editText part and event on button click, please if possible take a look to my adapter (Expandable_adapter class), how to implement a filter on it?

Comment: @Origin My requirement was to input a book ID from a fragment and pass it to a new fragment belonging to other activity which consists of list of users with the same book id. It might suit your requirement as well I guess, please give it a try.